# How can I get subscribe destination from UNSUBSCRIBE frame in Spring WebSocket STOMP

Tags: spring-websocket, stomp

I'm using Spring WebSocket STOMP. I need to save all subscribe destination from `SUBSCRIBE` frame and remove it in `UNSUBSCRIBE` frame, but how can I get destination from a UNSUBSCRIBE frame?

Answer (score 0):

The [`UNSUBSCRIBE`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#UNSUBSCRIBE) frame doesn't include the name of the destination. It only includes an `id` header which must match the `id` header provided by the client who originally sent the corresponding [`SUBSCRIBE`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SUBSCRIBE) frame. The STOMP broker implementation itself keeps track of the connection/id/destination relationship. If you wanted to perform your own logic when a client sends an `UNSUBSCRIBE` frame you'd need to keep track of this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I modified default id header in `SUBSCRIBE` frame as destination, like this below

```
subscription=stompClient.subscribe('/destination', function(data){
        if (data.body) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#response").text(data.body);
        } else {
            alert("got empty message");
        }
                
            },{ id: '/destination' });
```

then I get id from `UNSUBSCRIBE` frame

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `spring-boot-starter-websocket` does not give the destination from the `UNSUBSCRIBE` event. One way is to use the `simpSessionId` which remains same across the the session. If you are using stompjs, it includes a randomly generated id which remains same across the session.

You will have to maintain a map of sessionId -> destination and achieve your usecase.
Something like this

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketEventListener {

    private final Map<String, String> simpSessionIdToSubscriptionId;

    public WebSocketEventListener(){
        this.simpSessionIdToSubscriptionId = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSubscribeEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent sessionSubscribeEvent){
        String subscribedChannel = (String) sessionSubscribeEvent.getMessage().getHeaders().get("simpDestination");
        String simpSessionId = (String) sessionSubscribeEvent.getMessage().getHeaders().get("simpSessionId");
        simpSessionIdToSubscriptionId.put(simpSessionId, subscribedChannel);

    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleUnSubscribeEvent(SessionUnsubscribeEvent unsubscribeEvent){
        String simpSessionId = (String) unsubscribeEvent.getMessage().getHeaders().get("simpSessionId");
        String destination = simpSessionIdToSubscriptionId.get(simpSessionId);
        // do whatever you want with destination
    }
}
```